# View with union all locking tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view

In my SQL Server 12.0.5000.0 database I have a view similar to this that my application uses to read data:

```
 create view myview as  
SELECT [id], [another_id], [textdata], [datastamp] FROM [dbo].[table_0] UNION ALL   
SELECT [id], [another_id], [textdata], [datastamp] FROM [dbo].[table_1] UNION ALL   
SELECT [id], [another_id], [textdata], [datastamp] FROM [dbo].[table_2] UNION ALL   
SELECT [id], [another_id], [textdata], [datastamp] FROM [dbo].[table_3] UNION ALL   
SELECT [id], [another_id], [textdata], [datastamp] FROM [dbo].[table_4] UNION ALL   
SELECT [id], [another_id], [textdata], [datastamp] FROM [dbo].[table_5] UNION ALL   
SELECT [id], [another_id], [textdata], [datastamp] FROM [dbo].[table_6] UNION ALL   
SELECT [id], [another_id], [textdata], [datastamp] FROM [dbo].[table_7] UNION ALL   
SELECT [id], [another_id], [textdata], [datastamp] FROM [dbo].[table_8] UNION ALL   
SELECT [id], [another_id], [textdata], [datastamp] FROM [dbo].[table_9] UNION ALL
```

If I'm running a reindex on table 3 while I'm querying table 8 via this view, would this reindex cause locking?  I'm seeing some behavior that makes me think this might be happening.  I'm wondering about rewriting it like so:

```
 create view myview as  
SELECT [id], [another_id], [textdata], [datastamp] FROM [dbo].[table_0] with (nolock) UNION ALL   
SELECT [id], [another_id], [textdata], [datastamp] FROM [dbo].[table_1] with (nolock) UNION ALL   
SELECT [id], [another_id], [textdata], [datastamp] FROM [dbo].[table_2] with (nolock) UNION ALL   
SELECT [id], [another_id], [textdata], [datastamp] FROM [dbo].[table_3] with (nolock) UNION ALL   
SELECT [id], [another_id], [textdata], [datastamp] FROM [dbo].[table_4] with (nolock) UNION ALL   
SELECT [id], [another_id], [textdata], [datastamp] FROM [dbo].[table_5] with (nolock) UNION ALL   
SELECT [id], [another_id], [textdata], [datastamp] FROM [dbo].[table_6] with (nolock) UNION ALL   
SELECT [id], [another_id], [textdata], [datastamp] FROM [dbo].[table_7] with (nolock) UNION ALL   
SELECT [id], [another_id], [textdata], [datastamp] FROM [dbo].[table_8] with (nolock) UNION ALL   
SELECT [id], [another_id], [textdata], [datastamp] FROM [dbo].[table_9] with (nolock) UNION ALL
```

If I don't care about dirty reads I would think this would be okay.

Comment: No - don't start splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) to avoid a different problem and accept the risk of errors and incorrect information.

Comment: Rebuilding an index acquires a schema stability lock, it will block your query, using *nolock* will not help for a schema stability lock.

Comment: Perhaps a partitioned view (or table) would be a more appropriate solution?

Comment: @SMor Prepared to bet that a partitioned view won't prevent Sch-M problems, that comes from the compilation, whereas partitioned views help for short-circuiting the tables in the view when actually reading. Would be a good idea anyway